# how to install lua modules on linux

Tags: linux, module, lua, require, iup

i started programming lua on windows with "Lua for Windows", and plenty of good an necessary modules came with the package.

now i am trying lua on my linux at home and i cant figure out if there is similar way to install lua packages here?

specifically: for an own tea-timer-script i needed `sockets` and `iup`.
`lua` was already on my `linux mint` and i thought it will be easy from here. i could find `sockets` on the repository, but i could not find `iup`.
from there i tried `luarocks` with `sudo luarocks install iup` but i had no chance of finding it there. Also had problems with `luadist`.

How do you do it?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

[IUP - Building in Linux](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/en/building.html)

There are instructions for building from sources or using pre-compiled binaries.

Comment: i was looking for some way to easy install packages generally. what you wrote is not easy;) maybe a good repo?

Comment: Sorry, there is none. You can download the pre-compiled binaries we provide or compile the library yourself.